# ImageMagick - Replace the transparent part of a GIF with a solid colour?

Tags: images, conversion, gif, imagemagick

I have a GIF file that has a transparent section. I want to replace that with just plain white (or some other colour), so that there is no transparent parts. Can I do this on the command line with ImaageMagick? I'm OK if the image has to change from a .gif to something else. I tried to convert it to a jpg and the tramsparent parts were black. Is there a way to customize that?

I'm using ImageMagick on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using the 'convert' binary that comes with imagemagick.

`convert myimage.gif -alpha off myimage.gif`

Read about setting it to a custom color here:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#gif_trans